C# app.config keys when running unit tests
I've spent about an hour on this. I have an app.config that's in a unit test project. When I compile/build it, it ends up in the bin folder with everything else. However, when I run said unit tests, the app.config, in the bin folder changes with a different set of keys. I'm baffled how this is happening, especially since 2 other developers don't have this issue. I've even re-cloned my local repo and still getting the same results. Are there config settings I'm not thinking of?

I figured it out, our solution had a hierarchy for app.configs. It was a custom setting I wasn't aware of that I had to dig in to find. Depending on the environment, you project/app.config could get overridden by any number of other ones from other app.config in the solution. I've seen this done with web.configs but never with an app.config.

Unit test uses a different output .
Add item in csproj:
<Target Name="Copy" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="App.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.dll.config" />
</Target>

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22720#issuecomment-371018696

@joby-flick May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?

It's difficult to help without any code. However, when I hit such issues, it's usually something very trivial I may have overlooked. I create a quick console test application and try to reproduce the error with minimal code. The first step is find the problem :)

The problem is that the tests are failing because keys are getting removed from the app.config, therefore throwing null exceptions.
